# Multiple elements in ArrayAdapter - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm creating an array adapter for list view with 2 items (2 textViews).

I know how to add a single item to my adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.newsrow, R.id.titleTextView,myArray);
list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

But what should I do to add second textView (called contentTextView in my app) to the listAdapter?

Comment: you can use the add property: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: You can use [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) or your own custom adapter. Here is a nice [toutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your custom layout for your row.

**custom_row.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listview_layout">   
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listview_firsttextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listview_secondtextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Afterwards you will need a custom ArrayAdapter. To achieve this you will need to extend ArrayAdapter<> class, **example below:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private Context context;
    private List<String> strings;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> strings)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_row, order);
        this.context = context;
        this.strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.strings = strings;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);

        TextView your_first_text_view = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listview_firsttextview);
        TextView your_second_text_view = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_secondtextview);

        your_first_text_view.setText(strings.get(position));
        your_second_text_view.setText(strings.get(position)); //Instead of the same value use position + 1, or something appropriate

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

And for the last steps set the adapter to the appopriate ListView like this:

```
ListView my_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
CustomAdapter my_adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, my_strings);
my_list_view.setAdapter(my_adapter);
```

I hope this gives you an idea of setting custom adapters to your ListView.